# adding a loop to each part of an equation to label it

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can lebel each part of an equation (when I click it will go the the second term and so on) as in this image?,

[image]

Comment: This is beamer, yes? Please post a MWE to start with.

Comment: I have just a pdf :(, @GuidoJorg