# Label different parts of an equation by a square callout

Tags: tikz-pgf, callout

I posted this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243724/adding-a-loop-to-each-part-of-an-equation-to-label-it) a long time ago, where I wanted to produce an equation like the second page of this [lecture](http://einrichtungen.ph.tum.de/T30e/teaching/ws1314/SUSYslides16.pdf). Now I return to it and I use the answer of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84460/tikz-callout-pointing-to-nested-align-text-math-environment-not-displayed) as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, tikz, lmodern, xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes.callouts, shadows}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For align environement
\usepackage{color} % to define the next colors
\definecolor{blue(munsell)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.69}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycallout}{r<> O{} m m m m m m}{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
{\node[drop shadow, rounded corners, align=left, fill=#8!30, text width=#5,
#2,
draw,rectangle callout, anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(#6:#7cm)}]
at (#3) {#4};}
}
\newcommand{\refbox}[3]{
\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)]{ 
         \node[fill=#3!30, anchor=base, rounded corners] (#1) {#2};}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Quantum corrections to gauge interactions}
 \begin{align*} 
     &F(\Phi)= \only<1,3>{\alpha} \only<2>{\refbox{rb1}{$\alpha$}{blue}} X+\only<1,2>{g(\Phi)}  \only<3>{\refbox{rb2}{$g(\Phi)$}{blue}}
 \end{align*}
 \only<2>{\mycallout<2>{rb1}{tree level}{2cm}{44-1}{1}{blue}}\only<3>{\mycallout<3>{rb2}{one-loop}{2cm}{50--44}{1}{blue}}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

My question is: since I do not understand the above code I am wondering if this is the best way to write it?

**Edit:** A nice method is in the anwer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287089/shift-of-equation-elements-placed-in-a-tikz-rectangle)

Comment: You could use `\newcommand` but you would have to use a different syntax. The optional argument would need to come first and the first argument would have to be given in `{}` rather than `<>`. Or you could use lower level TeX stuff and `\def`, but that would not be recommended in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just look up the documentation for `\NewDocumentCommand`? `texdoc xparse`?

Comment: @cfr thank you for your answer. I don't understand it :( . So can you tell for example how to change the horizontale position of the comment and can one incorporate the `\only<>` command in the definition of the `NewDocumentCommand` ?

Comment: Yes. I mean, the only difference between `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\newcommand` which is relevant here is that the way the arguments are specified is different. Anything you can do with those arguments within the definition will work the same. So you can just make the changes you want as if it were using `\newcommand` and ignore the fact that it is using `\NewDocumentCommand` as you don't want to change anything about the user interface but only what the command does. So there shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: @cfr Ok, can I remove `O{ }` in `\NewDocumentCommand`? and how to  incorporate the `\only<1,2,..>` command in the definition of the `NewDocumentCommand` ?

Comment: You can remove it if you don't need an optional argument. As for the `\only`, that just depends what you want it to do. How should I know how to incorporate it when I have no idea what you're trying to do? That bit is just like `\newcommand`. There's nothing specific about `\NewDocumentCommand` there.

Comment: @cfr what I want is the best way to write the code in the question (I edited the question and made it more direct )

Comment: If you want to use the `<>` argument to your command, you can't define it with `\newcommand`. So you either need lower level `\def`, which isn't recommended, or `\NewDocumentCommand`. If you don't want to use the `<>`, then you can just use `\newcommand` and do away with `\NewDocumentCommand` altogether.